# Grafana aggregation issue when changing time range (%CPU and more)

Tags: aggregate, grafana

I have an % CPU usage grafana graph.

The problem is that the source data is collected by collectd as Jiffies.

I am using the following formula:

```
collectd|<ServerName>|cpu-*|cpu-idle|value|nonNegativeDerivative()|asPercent(-6000)|offset(100)
```

The problem is that when I increase the time range (to 30 days for example), the grafana is aggregating the data and since it is accumulative numbers (And not percentage or something it can make a simple average), the data in the graph is becoming invalid.

Any idea how to create a better formula?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the aggregation plugin (read type) to compute averages?

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Aggregation/Config

Comment: Thanks. I saw that. This is in the source (collectd).
I was more hoping to find a solution in grafana itself so I can use it for all the places I see this problem (Network BW for example)

Answer (score 0):

it is very strange that you have to use the nonNegativeDerivative function for a CPU metric. nonNegativeDerivative should only be used for ever increasing counters, not a gauge like metric like CPU